# how to duplicate all lines with vim nomal mode

Tags: vim

Using 3 letters selection: `vip` on this paragraph:

```
Hello
all
how are you
```

I would like to duplicate every line to get this:

```
Hello
Hello
all
all
how are you
how are you
```

I expect that work:

```
:'<,'>normal yyPjj
```

but I get

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
all
how are you
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably the most idiomatic approach:

```
:'<,'>g/^/t.
```

Breakdown:

- `:[range]g/<pattern>/<command>` executes `<command>` on every line matching `<pattern>` in `[range]`. See `:help :global`.
- `'<,'>` is our `[range]`, that covers the visually selected lines. See `:help :range`.
- `^` is our `<pattern>`, that matches BOLs. I like `^` for this but one could use `.` or `$` or whatever works for them, as long as it matches all the lines in `[range]`.
- `t.` is our `<command>`, that copies the current line below itself, essentially duplicating it. See `:help :t`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also record a macro into for example the `a` register with `qayypjq`.
Then you can run it with `@a` and repeat it N times with N`@a` (where N is some
number)